# Laravel - Get data by Month and sum it (varchar)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I´ve seen similar questions but honestly, I didn´t see anything that could take me to the right way and that´s because I´m also looking for a better way of doing this.

At certain point in my app i´m using chartjs, where i need to show months and then the values(sales). For that i know(or i think) i have to retrieve data **group by months**, and i got here so far:

```
$records = TabelaAngariacao::select('preco', 'created_at')
    ->where('estado', '=', 'Vendido')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($date) {
       return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
    });
```

Well...as you can see, I´m not **SUMING** anything, and that´s because in my database my values are getting stored in varchar(with dot´s!) and I know that´s not the proper way of doing things, but at this point changing everything it´s not a solution for me right now, **so how could i change that function in order to remove the dot´s and do a proper sum**? I have tried using CAST but it´s giving me undefined function.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time, regards.

**--EDIT--**

Hey everyone, i think i´m almost there, i didn´t know about the **transform function**, in there i can make some modifications on the preco(price) field which still has the problem of being a varchar, so i need to remove the dot´s in order for the sum to work, what i have is:

```
$records = TabelaAngariacao::select('preco', 'created_at')
            ->where('estado', '=', 'Vendido')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($date) {
                return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
            })->transform(function ($value) { //it can also be map()
                $nStr = str_replace(".", "", $value->pluck('preco'));
                return [
                    'preco_sum' => $nStr->sum()
                ];
            });
```

but this does not work, because $nStr is string...what do i need to do? if i convert to float, then the sum will not work...if i leave this way, the sum between 175.000 and 1.000.000 will be 176.000 which is wrong...any thoughts?

Comment: why not used `foreach` on result `query` next used `carbon` to put format on created at???

Comment: Can you show an example of the format of `preco` value?

Comment: Yes, at this point i have values like: 160.000 or 1.000.000 or 175.000 .... i know there are wrong and i saw something about removing the dots and summing, but i don´t know how to implement that.

Comment: does the dots represent thousands or they are decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

try this query .

```
$records = TabelaAngariacao::select(
   \DB::raw('sum(cast(preco as double precision)) as sums'), 
   \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months"))
->where('estado', '=', 'Vendido')
->groupby('months')->get();
```

Comment: Hi alexander, thak´s for answering, but  i need to sum the 'preco'(prices) and this field is varchar and using dot´s....what i am trying to achieve is the total amount per month

Comment: This is returning 10, 11, 12, 12 which means the months, but how do you wrap this in order to give you an array where the the preco(price) is summed? so the 12 only appears once but with the values summed?...i´m sorry but could you explain to me better?

Comment: try this new `query` sum per month

Comment: Hey Alexander, i´m getting this:  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'double)) as sums, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months from `tabelaAngariac' at line 1 (SQL: select sum(cast(preco as double)) as sums, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months from `tabelaAngariacao` where `estado` = Vendido group by months)

Comment: ok go to folder laravel go to `config`  -> database and search `strict` change to false

Comment: field preco is varchar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185833/discussion-between-alexander-villalobos-and-japa).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this to totalize and group by months

```
$ventas = Operacion::select([
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y') year"),
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m') month"),
            DB::raw("SUM(1) cantidad"),
            DB::raw("SUM(operacion_total) total"),
            DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 'OPEFIN' THEN operacion_total ELSE 0 END) total_finalizado")
        ])->groupBy('year')->groupBy('month')->get();
```

And if you need to cast some varchar you could do

```
CAST(operacion_total as DECIMAL(9,2))
```

so a column in select could be

```
DB::raw("SUM(CAST(operacion_total as DECIMAL(9,2))) total"),
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: Hi Manuel, your solution does not take in account that my field "preco"(prices) is a varchar...and the values inside this field have dots..like 175.000 ... i know it´s wrong but at this point i cannot change this

Answer (score 0):

Friend, if you want to make use of collection to group and also sum the values in group I believe its not too late.

Let's use the example below:

I'll make a sample result of your eloquent query with the following... Say we have users

```
    $users = collect();
    foreach (range(1, 9) as $item) {
        foreach (range(1, 9) as $ninja) {
            $users->push([
                'created_at' => \carbon('2018-0' . $item),
                'preco' => (string)'160.00' . $item
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The above should have something like this...

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "preco": "160.001"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "preco": "160.001"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "preco": "160.001"
  },
...
]
```

We then group by, and transform (or map) the result using...

```
   $users->map(function ($user) {
        $user['preco'] = str_replace('.', '', $user['preco']);
        return $user;
    })->groupBy(function ($user) {  
        return Carbon::parse($user['created_at'])->format('m');
    })->transform(function ($value, $key) { //it can also be map()
        return [
            'preco_sum' => $value->pluck('preco')->sum()
        ];
    });
```

Here we have the sum of each of the group of months...

**UPDATE**

If the record is big, then you can cut down the `map`ping by using [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

You could have something as follows that formats your 'preco' field in your model like so:

```
/**
 * Get the user's first name.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrecoAttribute($value)
{
    return str_replace('.', '', $value);
}
```

This means when Laravel is building the Eloquent objects, this value would be formatted as specified which means you can remove the first `map()` from the result.

> PS: you might need a mutator to change it to the format you want it in the database when saving.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, your answer is almost taing me to the right direction...because of the "transform" function, i can work the $value that has dot´s...how do you remove the dots in order to sum?

Comment: because the way you have it, it sums the wrong way because it´s considering the dot´s

Comment: @Japa You can run a map on the result as shown in my updated answer or you can create an Accessor See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators