# Laravel - return data group by month(and sum) and group by year

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this function below, which i got to it thanks to the help of **everyone** in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944966/laravel-get-data-by-month-and-sum-it-varchar) question:

```
$records = TabelaAngariacao::select('preco', 'created_at')
            ->where('estado', '=', 'Vendido')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($date) {
                return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
            })->transform(function ($value) { //it can also be map()

                $nStr = $value->map(function ($vl) {
                    return str_replace(".", "", $vl->preco);
                });
                return [
                    'preco_sum' => $nStr->sum()
                ];
            });
```

...this function is great, i had a problem because i´m saving the preco(prices) has varchar(which is wrong), but by using map i´m able to sum, and everything is working great giving me the result below:

```
10: {preco_sum: 160000}
11: {preco_sum: 220000}
12: {preco_sum: 1175000}
```

I have the months and the sum of them...but...then i realize i need to have the same thing but also related to the year, so i tried this:

```
return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m');
```

which leads me to this result:

```
"2018-10" => array:1 [▶]
"2018-11" => array:1 [▶]
"2018-12" => array:1 [▶]
"2019-01" => array:1 [▶]
```

but **how do i filter this by year on the client side?. I´m using chartjs, so one line should be all the months sumed OF 2018 and the same for 2017 for example.**

Thanks for your time, regards

Comment: you cant create one `array` and `push` this result next use `array_filter()` to get result for `year`

Comment: I´m trying to use: const arrYear = response.filter((value,index,array)=>{}); and then filter it somehow, but it doesn´t even let me use this function saying response.filter is not a function....response is what i received from server side which is the result i am showing in my question.

Comment: `filter function` is for `collection` you have array

Comment: you cant do it if upgrade your `query`

Comment: could you give me an example? because i think what you are saying is to filter everything in server side and then send it to client side...but i´m trying to filter it client side.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep the array in the same order? as you said you want to filter them? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: try to `cast` variable `preco` to `deciman or float` and `sum` same for `created_at` apply `date_format` and done you dont need apply `maps` and nothing more

Comment: i want the data to be splited by year